# Common mathematical functions in C++

Tags: c++, glibc

I have a very naive question regarding common C++ mathematical functions.

The mathematical functions listed here
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math

are they glibc functions or just high-level names that can be implemented in different ways? Am i correct in understanding the link above only specifies the interface that **all** C++ compilers should follow? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ones on that page are part of the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (link goes to November 2014 working draft), either unique to C++ or part of the included C library functions. The specific headers (listed on that page) for those functions and their corresponding sections are:

- `cstdlib`: Section 26.8 (pp. 1004-1008)
- `cinttypes`: Section 27.9.2.3-4 (pp. 1093-1094)
- `cmath`:  Section 26.8 (pp. 1004-1008)
- `numerics` (on the Numerics Library tab): Section 26.7 (pp. 1001-1004)

Primarily they are defined in section 26. The standard specifies the high level behavior of these functions, various properties and identities, etc., although does not specify low level implementation details such as precision requirements, etc. Many of the C library function descriptions defer back to the C standard with only notes on C++-specific changes given.

They will be declared in the standard C++ headers on your system and implemented somewhere accessible to you.

Note that glibc is the C runtime library used by many Unix-like systems, it's just a platform-specific implementation of certain C runtime functions. It does implement some of those functions for systems that use glibc.

By the way, to pick nits, the given link doesn't specify anything, it only documents. The specification is given in the standard itself; hopefully documentation such as what you linked to is well-maintained and correct.

Answer (score 1):

These functions are in std namespace - that constitute standard C++ runtime and you will find them in pretty much each compiler distribution.

They have nothing with [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) which is separate GNU C library.